# Balancing blocks, threads and workgroups?

Tags: multithreading, gpu, opencl, amd-gpu

I have an application (did not create myself) that requires three parameters

- Blocks
- Threads
- Points (number of calcs per thread I'm assuming)

It uses OpenCL and I have an RX 580. My current efficiency is low.

The GPU has 2304 modules in 36 compute units

Now I have played around with different values but I have no idea what would be the most optimal starting point because I don't know how blocks and threads relate to the compute units.
Any help would be greatly appreciated in understanding how to decide #of blocks, #of threads per block and #of calculations per thread.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make the same assumptions you have:

```
Blocks: Number of workgroups
Thread: Number of threads
Points: Some metric of work per thread
```

Its more important to set the correct **workgroup size** rather than the number of workgroups. You will want the group size to be a minimum of the SIMD width which is usually 32 on most GPUs. So blocks should be set to Threads / 32.

For "Points". This will depend on how much work is done per "calc". There is overhead with kicking off a workgroup so you want to make sure each thread has enough work to do. From experience ~16 instructions is usually enough. But if you can't see the kernel code then you will just have to experiment.

In summary:

1. Set "Points" so that you have at least 2304 threads for the work you need
2. Set Blocks to threads / 32

All of this is assuming you have at least 2304 work items otherwise you are not fully utilising your hardware.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful...but let me give you an example 
-b 112 -t 512 -p 256 ...this config seems to do the best but not sure how this relates to work items (and then I was reading about "grids" which I'm assuming is some matrix of tasks?) Would you happen to have an analogy for this?
My GPU has 36 compute units (tunnels) and each tunnel can handle 32 (cars) and each car/group can handle 2 threads (people) = 2304 ... and each person can handle 16 calculations? Sorry...I learn best through analogies :)